# Правильное ли окончание в глаголе?

Tags: окончания

Сотню крымчан ***выселят*** из опасных домов.

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше сказать так: "Около сотни крымчан выселят из опасных домов" Грамматическое сущ. сотня обычно не обозначает точное число, .да и вряд ли здесь может идти речь о таком точном количестве.

Answer (score 1):

**Сотню крымчан *выселят* из опасных домов.** Окончание в глаголе ***выселят*** верное.

Спряжение глагола выселить

```
Ед. число   Мн. число
```

1 лицо  выселю  выселим

2 лицо  выселишь    выселите

3 лицо  выселит **выселят**

Comment: ок, спасибо большое!